# What is the difference between Process: and Main PID: in the output of systemctl status?

Tags: systemd

What is the difference between the `Process:` and `Main PID:` lines in the output of `systemctl status` on a service unit?  What does the process number denote?

#### For example:

In the output from `systemctl status sshd` we see a line with `Process:` above the line saying `Main PID:`.  It has a different process number than the `Main PID:` line.  Here's one from [a RHEL admin guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-manage-start-and-autostart-ssh-service-on-rhel-7-start):

```
# systemctl status sshd
sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2014-09-01 09:35:17 EST; 2s ago
  Process: 6191 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd-keygen (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6194 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─6194 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

I'm trying to understand what that process number is.

Comment: You should edit your question to show the actual output of `systemctl`

Comment: Examples of what the questioner is asking about are not hard to find, everyone.

Answer (score 8):

`Main PID` is the PID of the process that is started using `ExecStart=` options (in the example `sshd`). The `Process:` is used for any other process that might have been started by the service using `ExecStartPre`, `ExecStartPost`, `ExecStopPost`, etc options. (in this example, `sshd-keygen` has been started using the `ExecStartPre=` option). You can have multiple lines on `Process:` if there are more than one processes started by the service, other than the main process. If there is no other process involved, you will only see the `Main PID` value.

I admit this is not very clear in the [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=) for `ExecStartPre` but the doc for `ExecStart` clarifies that the main process is the one started by that option, except for `Type=forking`, in which case, the daemon process is considered the main process.